# Derivation of F-distribution from inverse Chi-square?

Tags: anova, chi-squared-distribution, f-distribution

I am trying to derive F-distribution from Chi-square and inverse Chi-square. Somewhere in process I make a mistake and result slightly differs from the canonical form of Fisher-Snedecor F distribution. Please, help find it.

In order to derive p.d.f. of F-distribution, let us substitute the p.d.f. of chi-square and inverse chi-square distributions into F-distribution probability density function and integrate it over all possible values of $\chi^2_n=t$, such that $\frac{\chi_n^2}{\chi_m^2} = x$:

$f_{\frac{\chi_n^2}{\chi_m^2}}(x) = \int \limits_{t=0}^{\infty} f_{\chi^2_n}(t) f_{\frac{1}{\chi^2_m}}(\frac{x}{t})dt = \int \limits_{t=0}^{\infty} \frac{t^{n/2-1}e^{-t/2}}{2^{n/2}\Gamma(n/2)} \frac{{\frac{t}{x}}^{m/2+1}e^{-\frac{t}{2x}}}{2^{m/2}\Gamma(m/2)}dt = $

$ = \frac{1}{\Gamma(n/2)\Gamma(m/2) 2^{\frac{m+n}{2}} x^{m/2+1}} \int \limits_{t=0}^{\infty}t^{\frac{n+m}{2}}e^{-(t+\frac{t}{x})/2}dt = \frac{1}{\Gamma(n/2)\Gamma(m/2) 2^{\frac{m+n}{2}} x^{m/2+1}} \int \limits_{t=0}^{\infty}t^{\frac{n+m}{2}}e^{-\frac{t}{2}(1+\frac{1}{x})}dt$.

We aim to convert our integral into a gamma-function $\Gamma(n) = \int \limits_{0}^{\infty} z^{n-1}e^{-z}dz$.

In order to do that we shall perform a variable substitution $z = \frac{x+1}{x}\frac{t}{2}$, hence, $t = \frac{2x}{x+1}z$. Our integral then will take form of a gamma-function:

$\int \limits_{t=0}^{\infty}t^{\frac{n+m}{2}}e^{-\frac{t}{2}(1+\frac{1}{x})}dt = \int \limits_{z=0}^{\infty} (\frac{2zx}{x+1})^{\frac{n+m}{2}} e^{-z} \frac{2x}{x+1} dz = (\frac{x}{x+1})^{\frac{n+m}{2}+1} \cdot 2^{\frac{n+m}{2}+1} \cdot \int \limits_{z=0}^{\infty} z^{\frac{n+m}{2}}e^{-z}dz = \frac{x}{x+1}^{\frac{n+m}{2}+1} 2^{\frac{n+m}{2}+1} \Gamma(\frac{n+m}{2}+1)$

Substituting it into the expression for p.d.f., we get:

$f_{\frac{\chi^2_n}{\chi^2_m}}(x) = \frac{\Gamma(\frac{n+m}{2}+1)}{\Gamma(n/2)\Gamma(m/2)} \frac{2^{\frac{n+m}{2}+1}}{2^{\frac{m+n}{2}}} (\frac{x}{x+1})^{\frac{n+m}{2}+1} \frac{1}{x^{\frac{m}{2}+1}} = \frac{2\Gamma(\frac{n+m}{2}+1)}{\Gamma(n/2)\Gamma(m/2)} \frac{x^{\frac{n}{2}}}{(x+1)^{\frac{n+m}{2}+1}} = \frac{\Gamma(\frac{m+n}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{m}{2}) \Gamma(\frac{n}{2})} \frac{x^{\frac{n}{2}-1}}{(x+1)^{\frac{n+m}{2}}} \frac{2x}{\frac{n+m}{2}(x+1)}$.

As you can see the result differs from the canonical p.d.f. of F distribution $\frac{\Gamma(\frac{m+n}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{m}{2}) \Gamma(\frac{n}{2})} \frac{x^{\frac{n}{2}-1}}{(x+1)^{\frac{n+m}{2}}}$ by the multiplier $\frac{2x}{\frac{n+m}{2}(x+1)}$. Can you point to a mistake in this derivation?

Comment: @Xi'an Thanks for your comment. I suspected that it is Jacobian, but I don't see, why it is necessary here. I'm integrating with $dx = dt \cdot d\frac{x}{t}$, which looks like a normal square area region. But I have a feeling like Jacobian should be something like $\frac{1}{t}$, which will solve the problem.

Comment: @Xi'an Excuse me, I wanted to ask your advise again, if you don't mind. What I'm doing here is a line integral, not change of coordinates. So it seems that I must multiply the expression under integral by the length of unit arch segment. The unit arch = $\sqrt{dt^2+{d(\frac{x}{t})}^2} = \sqrt{dt^2 + (\frac{-x}{t^2}dt)^2} = dt \cdot \frac{\sqrt{t^4+x^2}}{t^2}$. This expression seems far too complicated.

Comment: @Xi'an I think I'll remove the update part. To be honest I still don't quite understand, why Jacobian here is applicable (I understand why we have to use it when we're changing coordinates e.g. from orthogonal to spherical - because the unit volume is changing - but here we are dealing with 1-dimensional integration along a curve, not a 2-dimensional integral, so I can't quite wrap my head around this). Anyways, this is going to be my "homework". Thanks again for showing me the way.

Comment: I find reasoning along the curve much more involved, as you have to determine the proper measure on that curve, a projection of the 2-d measure that eventually connects to the Jacobian. I am suprised that the approach that first changes the pair $(Z,Y)$ into the pair $(Z,X)$ and second marginalise over $Z$ is causing you headaches..!

Comment: @Xi'an The way you explain it, it sounds quite intuitive, indeed. Change coordinates from $(t,s)$ to $(t,x)$, where $x=ts$ and integrate over $t$ to get the marginal distribution over $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In
$$f_{\frac{\chi_n^2}{\chi_m^2}}(x) = \int \limits_{t=0}^{\infty} f_{\chi^2_n}(t) f_{\frac{1}{\chi^2_m}}(\frac{x}{t})dt$$
the Jacobian term is missing.

Indeed, if $Z\sim\chi^2_n$ and $Y\sim\chi^{-2}_m$, and if $X=ZY$, the joint density of $(Z,X)$ is
$$f_{\chi^2_n}(z) f_{\chi^{-2}_m}(\frac{x}{z})\left|\frac{\text dy}{\text dx}\right|=f_{\chi^2_n}(z) f_{\chi^{-2}_m}(\frac{x}{z})\frac{1}{z}$$
and
\begin{align*}f_X(x) &= \int_0^\infty f_{\chi^2_n}(z) f_{\chi^{-2}_m}(\frac{x}{z})\frac{1}{z}\,\text dz\\
&= K_{n,m} \int_0^\infty z^{n/2-1}e^{-z/2}(x/z)^{-m/2-1}e^{-z/2x}\frac{1}{z}~\text dz\\
&= K_{n,m} x^{-m/2-1} \int_0^\infty z^{(m+n)/2-1}e^{-(1+x)z/2x}~\text dz\\
&= K_{n,m} x^{-m/2-1} \{(1+x)/x\}^{-(m+n)/2+1-1}\int_0^\infty \zeta^{(m+n)/2-1}e^{-\zeta/2}~\text d\zeta\\
&= K^\prime_{n,m}\,\dfrac{x^{n/2-1}}{(1+x)^{(m+n)/2}}\\
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you once more for writing down your answer. However, adding the Jacobian term yields a wrong result (see **Update** section of my question). I don't think it should be a Jacobian, as we haven't changed the coordinates, rather, we are trying to calculate a line integral over a $y=\frac{x}{t}$ curve.